# Error on "sudo pod install"

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I already have one project working with a podfile.

I wanted to add a Podfile on an old project but I got this error on
`sudo pod install`

Error:

```
Resolving dependencies of `./Podfile'
Updating spec repositories
[!] git pull
Updating 35bbbaf..8b42708
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:

AFXAuthClient/1.0.4/AFXAuthClient.podspec

Please move or remove them before you can merge.

Aborting
```

It's weird because I don't use AFXAuthClient on my project, and I never used it.

Here's my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '5.0'
pod 'TTTAttributedLabel',  '~> 1.6.0'
pod 'ECSlidingViewController',  '~> 0.9.0'
```

I tried to made without success:

```
gem install cocoapods
pod setup
```

NB: I get the same error with **pod setup**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From the command line run `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods`

Then run `pod install` again. You shouldn't need the sudo.

This look like it's caused because there was a change to a spec and it's conflicting with running a `git pull`

Comment: I too can't merge after installed new version cocoapods, this helped me. Thx Keith!

Comment: hi , i am confused with your statement ,can you help me what is mean of "This look like it's caused because there was a change to a spec and it's conflicting with running a git pull" your answer ?

Comment: When the `pod` tool is updating its sources with the master specs repo it runs a `git pull` and it failed while it was doing that, most likely because something had been changed, probably not intentionally causing the pull to fail because it would otherwise be overwritten.

Comment: The team is wrestling with a bug in libgit2 -http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/

Comment: That was a while ago. Hopefully we're past that at this point.

Answer (score 3):

If you're seeing an error like this, it might be because [CocoaPods had to force-push their repo](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/). They suggest:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
```