# Error on pod install

Tags: cocoapods

I have a working project the uses a pod file for some weeks now. When I learned that some of my pods have update I tried to  'pod install' on got this weird error

```
    Analyzing dependencies
    [!] Pod::Executable pull

    Updating 1337455..e9f6e93
    error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:

AeroGear-Push/0.7.0/AeroGear-Push.podspec

AeroGear/1.2.0/AeroGear.podspec

BrynKit/1.3.0/BrynKit.podspec

BrynKit/1.3.1/BrynKit.podspec

CSURITemplate/0.3/CSURITemplate.podspec

EXiLE/1.0.2/EXiLE.podspec

FlurrySDK/4.2.3/FlurrySDK.podspec

FoundationExtension/0.39.1/FoundationExtension.podspec

FoundationExtension/0.39/FoundationExtension.podspec

GCDObjects/0.0.1/GCDObjects.podspec

HTAutocompleteTextField/1.2.1/HTAutocompleteTextField.podspec

HTAutocompleteTextField/1.2.2/HTAutocompleteTextField.podspec

HTAutocompleteTextField/1.2/HTAutocompleteTextField.podspec

IDMPhotoBrowser/1.1.2/IDMPhotoBrowser.podspec

Igor/0.5.0/Igor.podspec

KFOpenWeatherMapAPI/0.2.0/KFOpenWeatherMapAPI.podspec

NGSegmentedViewController/0.1.1/NGSegmentedViewController.podspec

PPiFlatSegmentedControl/1.3/PPiFlatSegmentedControl.podspec

PiwikTracker/2.0.0/PiwikTracker.podspec

SDWebImage/3.4/SDWebImage.podspec

libwbxml/0.11.2/libwbxml.podspec

wbxml/0.0.1/wbxml.podspec

    Please move or remove them before you can merge.

    Aborting
```

another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970877/error-on-sudo-pod-install) suggested using the 'rm -rf ~/.cocoapods' command line
but this caused my cocoapods to stop working all together for all project
now which ever project I try to 'pod install' I get the 'Unable to find a specification for..' error

> [!] Unable to find a specification for `CorePlot (= 1.3)`.

Comment: I had this issue after I was messing around and deleted a framework directory under the `Pods/` directory.

Answer (score 235):

If you landed here on or after January 30th 2014, there is a break in CocoaPods causing this. Please read the related blog post found here: http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/

or do:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
```

Comment: Wow, that's quite a bug. Glad I found this with just a little bit of googling.

Comment: This fixes the broken pod spec issue, but keep in mind you might need to reinstall your repo:  pod repo add yourrepo.git

Comment: What would it mean if "pod repo remove master" returns [!] Unknown arguments: remove master

Comment: @AriBraginsky Kyle Fuller is answering questions like this on twitter, perhaps this will help you: https://twitter.com/kylefuller/status/429204211478564865

Comment: @rmooney why might you need to reinstall your repo?

Comment: @AriBraginsky, I had the same error when using 0.2.5. Updating to 0.2.9 should fix it.

Comment: updated cocoapods and this helped fix my issue.  Thanks

Comment: This requires a good 700MB of data as on 19 Dec 2019. Do this only when you have time and good internet speed.

Answer (score 110):

The solution is to use `$sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods` to clean the cocoapods master repo and then `pod install` worked without any problems.

Comment: No need for `sudo` on this.

Answer (score 19):

**The 100% dead-work one-line command is:**

`sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods && pod setup && pod install`

I created the issue on GitHub traker:[#2185](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2185#issuecomment-44199769)

And the official answer is:

> This is issue which has already been
>   fixed by @irrationalfab with commit CocoaPods/CLAide@5e023ab.
>   So the fix should be available in the next release of CocoaPods. Just be patient

Answer (score 16):

If you need a clean master spec repo you can try

```
cd ~/.cocoapods/master
git reset --hard
```

or if you're on CocoaPods 0.23+, use `~/.cocoapods/repos/master`.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me.  I'm not sure how the subrepos for each project are setup by cocoapods, but just calling `git reset --hard` at the root repo didn't reset the changes that had been made to one of the child repos.  I ended up just removing my `.cocoapods` directory and starting over, though not everyone would be in the position to do this.

Comment: @eremzeit what do you mean by child repos?

Comment: Doing this might also work for you: (1) `git fetch origin` (2) `git clean -f` (3) `git reset  --hard origin/master`

Answer (score 8):

You are going to have to manually delete any local copies of the Specs repository and re-clone the new version of the Specs repository. You can do that with the following commands:

`$ sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
$ pod setup`

Answer (score 7):

when my projects get big and I have a large pod file, I run into this problem quite a bit.

My solution is as follows :

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod install
```

Comment: The downvote presumably is because it's a copy of Mark Edington's answer.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to fix permissions and files owner**

```
$ sudo chown -R user ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
$ sudo chown -R user ./Pods
$ sudo chown -R user ./Podfile.lock
$ sudo chmod -R 777 ./Pods

$ pod update/setup
```

Comment: Yes! That's, what I need! Any other methods helps only for a once "pod install: operation. Right now everything works great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Wow this one has been a real pain and everyone seems to have a different solution. For me this solution worked on multiple machines/environments on a few occasions:

#### Apparently there is a bug with `psych` that is causing the problem.

```
sudo gem uninstall psych
sudo gem install psych -v 2.0.0
```

There's a [lengthy conversation](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2908) over on the CococaPods repo about the issue and this fix.

Answer (score 0):

Just to share my own fix for this issue:

Since this is a git issue, you can use simple git commands to resolve it (See @AdamSharp's post). What worked for me was running

`git clean -d -f`

in `~/.cocoapods/repos/master`.  This recursively removes any untracked files and directories from the repo. I encourage you to run:

`git clean -d -f --dry-run`

Before you actually execute anything so you can see what it would do. Should it break your CocoaPods master repo, simply delete `~/.cocoapods/repos/master` and run `pod repo update`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this.
pod spec lint --sources='https://git.oschina.net/yourname/jqcpodspec,https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs' --allow-warnings --use-libraries

if your spec pass validation, then
pod repo push JQCPodSpec FMCommonModelLib.podspec --sources='https://git.oschina.net/yourname/jqcpodspec,https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs' --allow-warnings --use-libraries

Answer (score 0):

I have try 2 day so i give you 100% working method for mac m1 m2

Error: To set up CocoaPods for ARM macOS, run:
sudo gem uninstall ffi && sudo gem install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc