# Cocoapods setup stuck on pod setup command on terminal

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods, xcode5

```
MacBook-Pro:~ skbc$ pod setup --verbose
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:212: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777

Setting up CocoaPods master repo

Cloning spec repo `master` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` (branch `master`)
  $ /usr/bin/git clone 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' master
  Cloning into 'master'...
```

Have gone through resources provided by Cocoapods website, SO and few video tutorials. Nothing happening even after waiting for a couple of hours, however still trying to figure out what may be the problem is?

I would very much appreciate your comments and suggestions.

Comment: When I got this it was due to proxy authentication failure. Try connecting via another network if possible.

Comment: @CGRasterMouse:thanks for the suggestion,i am not getting your point please tell me little bit more..i am struggling for last 3 day!!

Comment: Cocoapods initialization took about an hour for me. In spite of `--verbose`, cloning step went silently. So I checked the size of `~/.cocoapods` directory to ensure it was still cloning. The size has increased to ~100Mb in the end.

Comment: @sanjay: what happens if you just do a `git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`? Does that work or does it also fail?

Comment: @NicholasSmith: didn't tried..!!i just focused on the direction/steps provided by Cocoapods on there website.

Comment: @vokilam: waited for nearly 3-4 hrs and my internet bandwidth is 512 kbps.

Comment: @sanjay is the size of the folder changing? try Nicholas Smith suggestion

Comment: @vokilam:a repo folder was created, however there was not a single file or folder present inside repo..

Comment: @vokilam:should i try this command suggested by @ Nicholas Smith on terminal directly..?

Comment: yes directly, you'll see progress message: `Receiving objects:  15% (19192/125876), 3.65 MiB | 17.00 KiB/s`

Comment: In another Terminal window, run `ls -ltah ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/.git/objects/pack/` and then run it again after another 30 seconds or so -- assuming things are still chugging along, you should see a `tmp_pack_` file that is slowly increasing in size each time.

Comment: @sanjay could you please accept my answer as a valid one? it would be very nice! Thanks

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755974/cocoapods-pod-install-takes-forever/38675146#38675146](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755974/cocoapods-pod-install-takes-forever/38675146#38675146)

Answer (score 420, accepted):

It is not stuck. I thought the same until I went to the "Activity Monitor" of the system and checked the "Network" tab.

Then you will see that something is being downloaded. A process called `git-remote-http` is in charge of this.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Just wait! It happened the same for me :)

Comment: and for me quitting this process was the quickest way to start the pod process once it was stuck on "Updating local specs repositories" on pod install

Comment: Any reason the download happening is so slow. (26 KB/s)

Comment: cool man, it works perfect, but seems when we already pull some data form git then there is still stack for  installing operation. how we can track if it works or not

Comment: Good directions, and indeed it finall started puling the files. Geez it was only  couple hundred MB.

Comment: `pod setup` is one time thing or do i have to it for every project ?

Comment: This answer + `pod setup --verbose` helped to calm my impatience with it

Comment: well i'm stuck on 92.4Mb. This is painful.

Comment: Thanks, after seeing Activity Monitor, I've decided giving up on Cocoapods forever.

Comment: for late joiners, here is the latest repo size: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022638/pod-install-is-staying-on-setting-up-cocoapods-master-repo

Comment: what if also in activity monitor also stops??? although i have stable internet connection

Comment: Why I am downloading 2Gb?

Answer (score 59):

To get a progression, you can clone master yourself:

```
pod repo remove master
git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
pod setup
```

Comment: I use command below to boost up the cloning time:
`git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git ~/.cocoapods/repos/master`

Comment: @AnNguyen CocoaPods 1.0.0 will not be officially supporting shallow clones anymore. It will even attempt to `--unshallow`: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5016

Comment: One whole date past and I found this solution. I my case I have to retype 'git clone' three times to download it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! At least it shows that something happening. ;)

Answer (score 49):

This might be due to the http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/ issue... You will have to remove the repo and re-setup it...

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
```

worked for me

Answered in below question as well,
[Error on pod install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224627/error-on-pod-install)

Comment: Do I need to do this or I should wait as suggested in the answer by @Manuel M. ?

Comment: Ha ha, even removing spec repo 'master' takes forever here... :/

Comment: In both cases *pod install* or, *pod setup* it updates local repository. We don't have choice wait as suggested by @Maunel M, it works after sometime.

Answer (score 13):

I think you need to follow the steps to get rid of the situation and also add `--verbose` to check whats is happening in front of each command
eg:

```
$ pod setup --verbose
```

- pod repo remove master
- pod setup
- pod install

Answer (score 10):

This is not Stuck or not doing anything its downloading/cloning repository (total size is around 360MB, I am not sure)

1) Open **Activity Monitor**

2) Select **Network** Tab

3) Check bellow **Google chrome** -> ***git-remote-https***

[image]

Comment: Downvoted as you gave the same answer that was selected as the correct answer 2 years before your posting.

Answer (score 5):

For insecure people like me who needs an assurance that cocoapods, in fact, is doing the work, try this. The slowest bottleneck is when cocoapods try to clone the entire repo (~300 MB) into `~/.cocoapods`

```
while true; do
  du -sh ~/.cocoapods/
  sleep 3
done
```

Answer (score 5):

For me in **China**

I have to use **SSH** and **--depth=1** to boost up!

```
pod repo remove master
git clone --depth=1 git@github.com:CocoaPods/Specs.git  ~/.cocoapods/repos/master 
pod setup
```

Comment: CocoaPods 1.0.0 will not be officially supporting shallow clones anymore. It will even attempt to `--unshallow`: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5016

Comment: Github and CocoaPods are discouraging `--unshallow`: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5007#issuecomment-194309832

Comment: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: @JordanJohnson try my answer if you haven't setup SSH keys for github.

Answer (score 5):

The time required for *Pod setup* **depends on your Internet connection speed.**
You can check **Activity Monitor** application regarding this.

[image: Screenshot 1]

It is recommended to use `pod setup --verbose` command instead of `pod setup.`

This verbose helps you to see detailed stats while pod is being setup.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with `pod install` and `pod update`.

The problem is that after executing any of these two commands. A process called git-remote-http in monitor activity shows that something is being downloaded. This has been an existing issue with pods and an issue has opened on github. I've tried a lot of the recommended solutions. I was finally able to install the firebase cocoapod on my project.

Go to

```
~/.cocoapods/repos
```

if there is a master file here, you will need to delete it.

You can do something like

```
sudo rm -R -i yourmasterdirectory
```

do pwd ... you should still be in `~/.cocoapods/repos`

if the above did not work try

```
pod repo remove master
```

Once you have done this run

```
git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
```

the next thing you need to do is to is run `git fetch --depth=2147483647` - this will convert your local repository of Podspecs to be a full clone as noted [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4989):

pod install and pod update should work fast as expected.

Answer (score 2):

To execute it, you must pay attention in your Internet connection... if it fails for a sec, the command won't continue, but terminal won't tell you what's happening.
If the command fails, continue trying... worked for me!
I've used that command!

*$ git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git ~/.cocoapods/repos/master*

Answer (score 2):

--VMWare Workstation--virtualizedMac--NetworkSetting--Problem

After like 100 tries I got it to work!
I have tried nearly everything described here but nothing solved the problem.
It randomly stopped by cloning into master between 0% and 97%. In Activity Monitor I saw the network traffic has stopped.

Finally I have changed the network setting from NAT to BRIDGE.
This was the solution!

Comment: Thank you, you saved me on this issue. MacOS VMWare, had same problem switched to bridge after doing control panel -> repair VMWare then repatching my VMWare for MacOS fixed bridge mode. After fixing bridge mode, and rerunning the setup it went smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Just setup the master repo, was excited to see that we have a download progress, see screenshot ;)

CocoaPods release 1.2.0 (Jan 28) fixes this issue, thanks to all contributors and Danielle Tomlinson for this release.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Might not be directly related to your issue, but for me I already had the repo cloned but an old library that I attempted to use was pointed at a different spec repo and I didn't actually need to clone **this** spec repo. To bypass cloning *another* spec repo I just went into the library's Podfile and removed `source` line. It instantly installed the pods, didn't have to clone another spec repo.