# on mac os sierra, stuck on "Setting up CocoaPods master repo"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, cocoapods, xcode8

After moving to mac os sierra, I completely formatted my mac now I'm facing problem to install cocoapods, every time I run `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`
every thing installed well, and when I try to install a pod, the terminal stack on `Setting up CocoaPods master repo` 
. 
Already updated the system with `sudo gem update --system` and still got the same problem, searched online to found old answers to use `pod install --verbose`

Ss I found in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022638/pod-install-is-staying-on-setting-up-cocoapods-master-repo) answer fail again tells to install it manually.

NOTE : I have the latest version of 'Command Line Tools'. Any suggestion or how to install master repo manually?

Comment: i also facing the same problem ,please answer this  if any one have idea for cocoapods installation on new os Sierra 10.12 version .

Comment: The problem is that you are running cocoapods in a "new" environment so it needs to update the index of all the repositories registered on cocoapods. That process takes a lot of time depending on your internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/21852985/1033581:

> on 4th Nov 2016, the repo is **1.07 GB**

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/33699136/1033581:

> To get a progression, you can clone master yourself:
>
> ```
> pod repo remove master
> git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
> pod setup
> ```

Comment: And the most important thing is your internet connection speed.

Answer (score 0):

In my first installation, I got the same problem too, it takes too much time in "setting up master repo".

Actually, you can see it through "activity monitor" that it's actually  downloading, but it seems the connection is slow from the server.

Try these steps, it solves my problem:

```
1. pod setup
```

It will do "setting up master" again, don't wait, continue these steps below:

```
2. Ctrl +C
3. pod repo remove master
4. cd ~/.cocoapods/repos 
5. git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
```

It takes less than 7 minutes for me (I think it depends on internet connection), then I can do `pod install`.