# Pod install takes too long time

Tags: cocoapods, podfile

I'm trying to install my pods with `pod install`, it prints

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
```

and it takes too long time and nothing installing. Is that a bug or that's my mistake? Can I fix that problem?

Comment: It normally take some time, so just wait

Comment: Try out pod install --verbose. It will output, what is happening during installation

Comment: @UmairAfzal but not 10+ minutes =/

Comment: It depends on your network speed, If your network is slow, generally it takes the longer time.

Comment: No, its very normal since the repo is VERY HEAVY, and git sever sucks, so you should wait, might take 30 mins - 1 hours depends

Comment: @ImadAli I think 100 mbit/s is a good speed for installing pods :)

Comment: @ArtemZaytsev I checked that already, it prints `Cloning into 'master'...`

Comment: First time pod takes time.Patience :)

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan it's not my first time installation :)

Comment: @J.Doe, currently main repo of CocoaPods is about 800Mb, and I think GitHub is intentionally limiting network channel for downloading it. http://thenextweb.com/dd/2016/03/08/cocoapods-popular-basically-took-five-github-servers/

Comment: oh, it installed after 30(!) minutes!

Comment: http://blog.cocoapods.org/Master-Spec-Repo-Rate-Limiting-Post-Mortem/

Comment: Yes, it takes a time, wait until complete update,because if u pause or stop progress and try to start again then it also take same more time

Comment: Same, download speed 33kb/s .. .wtf

Answer (score 13):

Yes these problems often occur in first time installation.

So these are what I did to solve it:

```
1. pod setup
```

It will do "setting up master" again, DONT' WAIT, continue these steps below

```
2. Ctrl +C
3. pod repo remove master
4. cd ~/.cocoapods/repos 
5. git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
```

It takes around 5 minutes for me (I think it depends on internet connection), then I can do "pod install".

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40541430/3258003

Answer (score 7):

Expanding my comment.

CocoaPods is so popular and heavy, so GitHub is limiting rate for downloading.

> From user `mhagger`, an engineer on GitHub’s infrastructure team:
>
> > The slow fetches and clones (which sometimes time out) that the CocoaPods community is experiencing are caused by automatic rate limiting on our servers, which is done to make sure that extremely high levels of load in one repository cannot impact other GitHub users. The CocoaPods/Specs repository is more or less permanently being rate limited.
> >
> > There have been approximately 1.1 Million clones/fetches from CocoaPods/Specs in the past week. This activity has kept, on average, more than 5 server CPUs permanently pegged, and used several terabytes of bandwidth out of our datacenters. There are only a handful of other repositories in all of GitHub that even come close to this level of activity. As far as I know, this level of activity is not new, but has been going on for many months and probably longer. Suffice it to say that the name CocoaPods/Specs is quite well known within our team.

http://thenextweb.com/dd/2016/03/08/cocoapods-popular-basically-took-five-github-servers/

Answer (score 0):

I tried various solutions, nothing worked. Downloading 100MB took me about 30 minutes.

Then I connected via VPN to a server in the US and ran `pod install --verbose` again, download speed went up and installing 100MB took 20 seconds.

Looks like download speed is limited for some locations (in this case South America).