# Cocoapods installation problems

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am trying to install `Cocoapods` on a mac running MacOS Sierra. After writing `"sudo gem install cocoapods"` (getting no error), I entered `"pod setup"`. However, my terminal just gets stuck on the line `"Setting up CocoaPods master repo"`.

Can anyone help me identify my mistake? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it can take long.

You could try running in verbose mode:

```
pod install --verbose
```

This'll show you what `cocoapods` is up to.

`pod install` or `pod setup` fetches whole repo with history when you first time run it.

If You don't need that commit history then.

```
pod setup
Ctrl +C
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos 
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
```

Comment: When i type in pod install --verbose, I get an error like this: "[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory." Any idea why?

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902497/cannot-install-cocoapods-no-podfile-found-in-the-project-directory

Comment: Unfortunately, I still think it is something wrong with my installation of cocoapods itself... After going into a specific folder with an xcode project, I typed "pod install" and this is what it gave me "Setting up CocoaPods master repo". Then it's stuck... Do you know why?

Comment: Also, I tried "pod setup --verbose" and it gets stuck after "Cloning spec repo `master` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` (branch `master`)
  $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
  Cloning into 'master'..."... Should I just wait or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a general problem because how heavy cocoapod is. It's a popular library and have high amount of load to their sever.

So these are what I did to solve it:

```
1. pod setup
```

It will do "setting up master" again, DONT' WAIT, continue these steps below

```
2. Ctrl +C
3. pod repo remove master
4. cd ~/.cocoapods/repos 
5. git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
```

It takes around 5 minutes for me (I think it depends on internet connection), then I can do "pod install".

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40541430/3258003