# terminal doesn't show downloading/installing pods library

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, cocoapods

hey guys i m using Xcode 7.2 and iOS 9.0 i am try to install cocoa pods.

[image]

when type password it accept password but as you see in image not installing/download any libraries

how may i solve this problem please help me.
thank in advance.

**note:** i refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25257238/9137841

Comment: i think you wan to install some lib for your project right ? and what you are showing is the installation of cocoa pods to your system not in your project ..

Comment: i want to install or update  cocoapods on my mac

Comment: try this "sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods"

Comment: Use `--verbose` to see the status, It will take a while to install ~20--30mins, it might look freeze but its not

Comment: not working yet

Comment: @Tj3n means i want to wait 20 or 30 min

Comment: thanks guys now it working

Comment: @SharathKumar as you see Tj3n comment i think it will not work or freeze but it take time and refer my question link

Comment: @SharathKumar yup

Answer (score 0):

> You can find information of downloading pod here

- open "activity monitor" in your mac.
- [Activity Monitor] -> [network tab] -> [git-remote-http]
- git-remote-http is your pod process

[Cocoapods setup stuck on pod setup command on terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680573/cocoapods-setup-stuck-on-pod-setup-command-on-terminal)