# Cocoapods staying on "analyzing dependencies"

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm using cocoapods to manage my dependencies. All have been working fine. Now, When I'm creating a new project, added the following to my podfile,

```
platform :ios, '6.1'
pod 'RestKit', '~>  0.20.0'
```

when i'm doing pod install, it is continually staying on **analyzing dependencies**.

Any idea why this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224627/error-on-pod-install

Comment: Run with the `--verbose` switch and paste any output you see here.

Answer (score 384, accepted):

I had the same problem, and since my output with --verbose was different than the linked SO answer, I'm including that response along with a verification that it worked for me:

```
  $ pod repo remove master
  $ pod setup
  $ pod install
```

Comment: Weird. My cocoapods worked great for a really long time, then just stopped. This fixed it! Thanks

Comment: when ever you install a new version of xcode we need to do follow these steps

Comment: wow. work like a charm, and no tutorial mentions this :( thanks :)

Comment: Just FYI, I had this same issue then I realized that I had un-commited changes to my project. I simply staged & committed them, ran ```$ pod install``` again and it worked.

Comment: works sometimes, but it is helpfull to append --verbose at end of each command to track details of $ pod setup where it might get stuck again

Comment: @Developer um.. that's a pretty bold statement. can you tell us how/why? A reference wouldn't hurt

Answer (score 14):

Another way to fix that is to delete the `Pods` folder and the `Podfile.lock` file and run `pod install` again.

Comment: Tried it but I'm still stuck at Analyzing dependencies

Answer (score 5):

As of [CocoaPods version 1.8.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/8923) `trunk` is used instead of `master`. So you need to execute the following commands:

```
$ pod repo remove trunk
$ pod setup
$ pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

Something that seemed to work for me:

- Cancel first attempt using **Ctrl-C**
- Reattempt using **pod install**

Also, once the pod has installed successfully, be sure to close the current project before opening the project.workspace.

Answer (score 0):

i2097i's comment was the fix for me (so I can't take credit for this, and can't seem to upvote his comment).

Check for any uncommitted changes (I had just added my Podfile but it was not committed). Staging and committing got `pod install` working.

Comment: seems like a helpful answer to me

Comment: @gndp This is a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

$ pod repo remove trunk

$ pod setup

run above two commands it will solve problem

Comment: Could you add more of an explanation? What do these terminal commands do?

Answer (score 0):

```
pod repo update
pod install
```

easy and quick fixed my problem