# cocoapods - 'pod install' takes forever

Tags: ios, command, cocoapods, repo, pod-install

I was trying to update the existing pods with the `pod install` command, but it takes forever to run.

The verbose mode shows it was stuck at the following line (forever)

> Updating spec repo `master`
>
> $ /usr/bin/git pull --no-rebase --no-commit

There is no network activity after it gets stuck.

Comment: after being stuck for 90 mins, `pod install` proceeds to next stage. I  guess I am not very patient.

Comment: run pod install --verbose to see more debugging information. The general situation is git updating take too much time. If you don't need update, run pod install --no-repo-update

Comment: Says something about the quality of pod. Those guys need to fix that soon. I am getting stuck on this everytime I have to deal with pod.

Comment: Why are there 17,000+ directories in this specs folder? Is it keeping all the dependency info in the app itself?

Comment: 90minutes? OMG. What is your internet speed, Hai Feng Kao?

Comment: @Rocotilos It's nothing to do with my internet speed. There is a post about it: `CocoaPods is so popular it’s straining GitHub’s servers` http://www.techsite.io/p/276312

Comment: @HaiFengKao, I was worried because my internet is not good.I tracked it, it was about 350MB being downloaded. Thx for the link, I think cocoapods need its own server.

Comment: Still equally slow 5 years on. 20k a second for a huge file. Ridiculous.

Comment: Notice updated answer for 2019: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58577253/2942294

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680573/cocoapods-setup-stuck-on-pod-setup-command-on-terminal

Comment: 2022 and they don't fix it

Comment: Neither 2023.. weird.

Comment: 2024, 2030... because you assume that there is someone that actually cares about that. I'm pretty sure that cocoapods have been dead for at least 10 years.

Answer (score 567):

I ran into the same problem, and I solved it by running the following commands which is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006683/cocoapods-staying-on-analyzing-dependencies)

```
pod repo remove trunk
pod setup
pod install
```

Comment: cocoapods - 'pod repo remove master' takes forever. Need to create new thread ? :)

Comment: Thanks , it work for me.and also you can add --verbose to show detail debug info

Comment: @dmitrynikolaev at first I thought pod repo remove master also takes forever. But turns out I just need several minutes more to wait. Your needed time may vary because I don't know your pods configuration, but just give it more time.

Comment: It would be nice to add an explanation to the given solution to make it clear.

Comment: The actual downloading takes time due to network bandwidth. We can check through Activity Monitor - Network tab - for process 'git-remote-http'. We need to have patience. You may refer this answer link - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21916507/2641380

Comment: Even pod setup stuck at following,   
  $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master   
  Cloning into 'master'...   
You can skip pod setup instead "Go to ~/.cocoapods/repos and run  
'git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master'

Comment: pod setup can also be stuck sometimes at 'cloning into master'. You can try cloning the repo yourself by going to  '~/.cocoapods/repos' and running 'git clone http://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master' as Ammar suggested.

Comment: Still took forever and even with --verbose it's not exactly clear what the holdup is. Best just go for lunch while it runs.

Answer (score 215):

you can run

```
pod install --verbose
```

to see what's going on behind the scenes.. at least you'll know where it's stuck at (it could be a git clone operation that's taking too long because of your slow network etc)

to have an even better idea of why it seems to be stuck (running verbose can get you something like this

```
-> Installing Typhoon (2.2.1)
 > GitHub download
 > Creating cache git repo (~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/0363445acc1ed036ea1f162b4d8d143134f53b92)
 > Cloning to Pods folder
       $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon.git ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/0363445acc1ed036ea1f162b4d8d143134f53b92 --mirror
       Cloning into bare repository '~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/0363445acc1ed036ea1f162b4d8d143134f53b92'...
```

is to find out the size of the git repo you're cloning.. if you're cloning from github.. you can use this [format](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/):

```
/repos/:user/:repo
```

so, for example, to find out about the above repo type

```
https://api.github.com/repos/typhoon-framework/Typhoon
```

and the returned JSON will have a size key, value. so the above returned

```
"size": 94014,
```

which is approx 90mb. no wonder it's taking forever! (btw.. by the time I wrote this.. it just finished.. ha!)

---

**update:**
one common thing that cocoa pods do *before* it even starts downloading the dependencies listed in your podfile, is to download/update its own repo (they call it [Setting up Cocoapods Master repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022638/pod-install-is-staying-on-setting-up-cocoapods-master-repo).. look at this:

```
pod install --verbose

Analyzing dependencies

Updating spec repositories
  $ /usr/bin/git rev-parse  >/dev/null 2>&1
  $ /usr/bin/git ls-remote
  From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
  09b0e7431ab82063d467296904a85d72ed40cd73  HEAD
  ..
```

the bad news is that if you follow the above procedure to find out how big the cocoa pod repo is.. you'll get [this](https://api.github.com/repos/CocoaPods/Specs): "size": 614373,.. which is *a lot*.

so to get a more accurate way of knowing how long it takes to just install your own repo.. you can set up the cocoa pods master repo separately by using `pod setup`:

```
$ pod help setup
Usage:

$ pod setup

  Creates a directory at `~/.cocoapods/repos` which will hold your spec-repos.
  This is where it will create a clone of the public `master` spec-repo from:

      https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs

  If the clone already exists, it will ensure that it is up-to-date.
```

then running `pod install`

Comment: This is the **only** coherent description of "_WTF_" cocoapods are "up to"... that I've ever seen.

Comment: the download of the master repo took me 20 minutes staring at just a blinking cursor (and i have only a 150Mb internet connection and just a lousy macbook pro retina i7)

Comment: There are 17,000+ files/directories in the specs directory. It's not the most git friendly approach to whatever the heck it is they're doing there.

Comment: When I ran this command, my cocoapods showed me that it was finished. with its install. Thank you!

Comment: Most of the time it's about a big dependency that takes a lot of time to download

Comment: For me, it's downloading a 104MB file for `Installing boost (1.76.0)` and my internet is fine but it's still downloading at a slow speed.

Answer (score 56):

Updated answer for 2019 - the cocoa pods team moved to using their own CDN which solves this issue, which was due to GitHub rate limiting, as described here: https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.7.2/

TL;DR
You need to change the source line in your `Podfile` to this:

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
```

Comment: This made no difference for me.

Comment: from Cocoapods 1.8 it is default value - so for me it was helpful to remove source that lead to GitHub to fallback to default value (mentioned in this answer cdn.cocoapods.org). It decreased getting updates for more than 15 minutes

Comment: This little change saved me more than 10 minutes. Executing "pod install" now takes less than 2 minutes, while before making this changes it took about 12 minutes.

Answer (score 31):

### Possible solutions:

1. Updating Cocoa Pods may solve this issue
2. Clean and fresh install pods again

---

### Updating CocoaPods

Open terminal and type:

```
$ sudo gem update cocoapods
```

---

### Reinstall Pods

#### Step 1

Remove all the pods from your project (**tricky part**):

**Manually**

1. Remove all Pods records on **Build Phases** of your project (Marked Red)

[image]

2. Remove **libPods.a** under **Frameworks** folder

[image]

3. Now head to project directory and remove **Podfile.lock*, **Pods** folder and Workspace (Remove from **Trash** too).

**Automatically using [CocoaPods De-Integrate](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate)**

Install

```
$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods-deintegrate
```

Run

```
$ pod deintegrate
```

---

### Step 2

Here we are going through at installing the Pods again

**Change** your location your directory

```
$ cd yourprojectdirectory
```

**Edit** podfile by adding lines you need to it

```
$ open -a Xcode podfile
```

or

```
$ nano podfile
```

**FINALLY** install the pod again

```
$ pod install
```

---

Hope this helps

Comment: useless. Just did a fresh install of cocoapods, pod init and pod install just hangs for ever

Comment: @woens Well it depends on what libraries you are fetching. You can try also this [tool](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate) which de-integrates the pods from the project, and then run install again

Comment: none! thats the whole point. this happens when you start with init, then install on an empty project.

Comment: @woens What do you mean by none? Where is the point to install pods when there is no pods at all (if I understood you correctly)?

Comment: just starting an empty project and prepare it to add things later. so: create an xcode project, run pod init, run pod install. At this moment pod install hangs.

Comment: Actually @abbood gave the right answer: it needs to download a repository with 94000 entries. this took 20 minutes. (with a 150Mb internet connection on a i7 macbook pro)

Comment: my project fully error after run command "pod deintegrate"

Answer (score 23):

I found another way to solve the problem

`pod install --verbose --no-repo-update`

it works for me.

Comment: Still have to clone the first time.

Answer (score 14):

As pointed out here [git-remote-http process running in background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21916507/1586606). I goto this process from Activity Monitor and quitting this process resumed the pod process which was stuck on "**Updating local specs repositories**" after POD INSTALL

Answer (score 14):

As of 15th August 2016, the repo is a massive 2.39GB file. I opened the Activity Monitor to look at what the terminal was doing. It was downloading this huge file.

Answer (score 11):

This is what worked for me :

1. Delete all the content under `~/.CocoaPods`
2. Delete your existing `Podfile.lock` and `Pods` folder.
3. Leave your PodFile intact.
4. Run `sudo gem install cocoapods --verbose`
5. Run `pod install --verbose`

I recommend using the --verbose flag since Terminal is not great when giving progress on a command action. The verbose option helps a lot!

Comment: Beware that the master repo at ~/.cocoapods is huge (~1GB), so deleting and reinstalling it takes a long time. If I had realized this, I would have tried `pod install --verbose` before resorting to deleting the master repo.

Answer (score 9):

Just go through the below step-by-step:

Download https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/archive/master.zip

RUN the Below commands in terminal:

`pod setup --verbose`

Open new tab in the terminal and RUN

`mv ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/.git ~/tempSpecsGitFolder`

open master.zip (unzipping it)

`mv Specs-master ~/.cocoapods/repos/master`

`mv ~/tempSpecsGitFolder ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/.git`

cd [project folder]

pod install --no-repo-update

Answer (score 6):

Try clearing your CocoaPods cache, re-download and re-install all pods as described [here](https://gist.github.com/mbinna/4202236)

```
rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"

rm -rf "\`pwd\`/Pods/"

pod update
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in other answers, It takes forever because the size of cocoapods master repo is huge. This time can be reduced using the following steps.

1) Create a private specs file path on your github repository. Provide this path https://github.com/yourpathForspecs.git' as a source in your podfile.

2) identify ALL the repositories You need and their dependencies( mentioned in the podspec.json file on cocoapods for these repositories) and get their podspec.json files from cocoapods. add these podspec.json files with their folder ( say the latest version folder for bolts) in this specs repository.

3) remove the source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' in the podfile

4) pod update

This will take significantly less time as this requires fetching and downloading just the pods you need instead of whole cocoapods repository. 
In My case it reduced the pod update time from 15-20 mins on average to 3-4 mins at most.

Answer (score 2):

Even I was thinking the same. If you open `Activity Monitor` you can see that it is downloading something at there on the name of GIT.

I found this tip useful.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21916507/563735

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I then realized that I was still running Network Conditioner on "Very Bad Network". Turning that off solved the issue.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue like that:

```
rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods && \
gem update --system && \
gem update && \
gem cleanup && \
pod setup
```

Reference: http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/

Comment: My `pod setup` was taking forever and I aborted after 30minutes. I just followed this procedure and the `git clone` now finished after about 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. After running

```
pod install
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
```

The iterm2 was stuck on Setting up CocoaPods.

I solved the issue by running

```
sudo gem install CocoaPods
```

This is mentioned in the [CocoaPods website](https://cocoapods.org/)

Answer (score 1):

After a half of the day of investigating why `Analyzing Dependencies` takes forever, I found out that I was installing the latest `Firebase` pod (7.1.0), which relies on `GoogleAppMeasurement` version 7.1.0, and there was another pod, which is an ad mediation framework, which includes `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK`. This SDK was relying on a much lower version of `GoogleAppMeasurement` ~ 6.0.
I was able to install the pods by commenting out the conflicting pod from the ad mediation.
Something like this:

```
# Ad network framework
  pod 'SomeMediationNetwork/Core'
#  pod 'SomeMediationNetwork/GoogleMobileAds' # - the conflicting pod
  pod 'SomeMediationNetwork/Facebook'
  pod 'SomeMediationNetwork/SmartAdServer'
  pod 'SomeMediationNetwork/Mopub'
```

I had to contact the ad mediation library publisher to fix this issue, most probably by updating to the latest `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK` pod and releasing a new version.

I hope this one helps some other folks who are banging their head

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything on this page, nothing worked. Downloading 100MB took me about 30 minutes.

Then I connected via VPN to a server in the US and ran `pod install --verbose` again, download speed went up and installing 100MB took 20 seconds.

Looks like download speed is limited for some locations (in this case South America).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes happen to me too and I simply:

```
pod clean
pod update --verbose
```

Comment: There are no commands like `pod clean` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for me in 11.2019**

Hello i tried a lot of things, but nothing worked. Try just to connect to this site *https://cdn.cocoapods.org/* if you can't so just use VPN and do `pod install` etc. And don't forget to use `--verbose` for understanding what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative way to download cocoapods is to download one of the snapshots available [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/releases/tag/20161019). It is a bit old but the .bz2 compressed file was much faster to download. Once I had downloaded it, I copied it over to `~/.cocoapods/repos/` and then I unzipped it using `bzip2 -dk *.bz2`.

The unzipping took a while and once it was over, I changed the extension of the newly uncompressed file to .tar and did `tar xvf *.tar` to unzip that. This will show the list of files being created and will also take a while.

Finally when I ran `pod repo list` while inside the project folder, it showed the master folder had been added as a repo. Because I still kept getting an error that it was unable to find the specification for the pod I was looking for, I went to the master folder and did `git fetch` and then `git merge`. The git fetch took the longest, about an hour at 50 KB/s. I used fetch and merge instead of pull, as I was having issues with it, i.e. `fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly`. It is now up to date and I was able to get the pod I wanted.