# cocoapods: pod update and pod install takes forever

Tags: cocoapods

I try to update my podfile using the command `pod update` but it takes forever.
I did also all the steps according to this question [cocoapods - 'pod install' takes forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755974/cocoapods-pod-install-takes-forever) but nothing changed.
Using the command `pod update --verbose` i see that it stops here: `Updating spec repo master
  $ /usr/bin/git pull --ff-only`
Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cocoapods - 'pod install' takes forever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755974/cocoapods-pod-install-takes-forever)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CocoaPods has to download a repository of all podspecs to do its work. It seems like it's that pull operation that's taking a long time. I'm not aware of any way to accelerate that process.

However subsequent pod operations will be much faster until new commits are available in the master spec repo. So if you have several update or install operations, doing them together can save you some time.

Comment: Thanks for the hint..It appears that indeed takes a long time..It took hours for podfile to be updated.But finally got updated.

Comment: Thanks for actually mentioning "hours" @euthimis87  While I am 2 hours into my install, I was starting to wonder what "takes forever" actually means. 40 minutes? a week?

Answer (score 2):

There is a rate limiting on git servers and that seems to slow down the process.
Like Fabian said there is no valid solution at the moment but splitting the update to individual pods. There is an explanation at the CocoaPods blog [Master spec-repo rate limiting post‑mortem](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Master-Spec-Repo-Rate-Limiting-Post-Mortem/), it seems we need to wait for `1.0.0.beta.7` before they fix the issue. 
Meanwhile, this [Git Issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4989) on the topic recommends to run convert your Podspecs to be a full copy instead of a shallow clone, by running:

```
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos/master && git fetch --depth=2147483647
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run

```
pod install --verbose
```

to see what's going on behind the scenes.. at least you'll know where it's stuck at (it could be a git clone operation that's taking too long because of your slow network etc)

check this for more clarified answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25658514/1894306