# CocoaPod error in .pch file

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cocoapods

I have installed two CocoaPods: `PEPhotoCropEditor` and `MBProgressHUD`. Both are working perfectly, but today when I have tried to install `AFNetworking` pod the process was stuck at the same place and no further progress was seen. Therefore I have cancelled the process with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> which lead to the process stopping, but when I opened my project I got an error related to the other pods too. Here is my Error:

**This is my 1st error in MBProgressHUD**

> Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

**This is my second error in PEPhotoCrop Editor**

> /Users/infopride/Desktop/dummyx/Project name/Pods/:4:10: '/Users/infopride/Desktop/dummyx/projectname/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-PEPhotoCropEditor/Pods-PEPhotoCropEditor-prefix.pch' file not found.

**What I have tried:-**

1. install commandline tool again
2. uninstall and install cocoa pods again

When I am trying set repo it stuck at same place with no progress seen. (I have waited for 20 to 25 min.)

**Here is a screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing `AFNetworking` from your Podfile and running `pod update` again?

Comment: Instead of cancelling the `pod install` why not try and figure out whats actually causing the slowdown? `pod install --verbose`. Then you can see what process is sticking, chances are something is failing to pull down and by cancelling the process you have to start it all over again.

Comment: @tilo :- i tried with removing AFNetworking but still getting same issue.

Comment: @squarefrog :- i tried with `pod install --verbose ` it stuck at                                  `$ /usr/bin/git pull                                                                                                 --ff-only`                                          inshort full detail is                                        `Preparing

                                 Analyzing dependencies

                               Updating spec repositories
                         Updating spec repo 'master'
                            $ /usr/bin/git pull --ff-only`

Comment: pulling the repo can take a long time with slow internet. This time, try `pod install --no-repo-update`. But you really should update the specs repo - do `pod repo update` before going to lunch or bed, and let it just do its thing.

Comment: There is no slow internet issue. i have checked it. now i leave this topic i restored my old backup and start modification on it. due to time issue. Thanks a lot for response.

Comment: Have you read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755974/cocoapods-pod-install-takes-forever)?

Comment: @Droppy: yes i have read all the question related to .pch file or cocoa pods means set or else. i tried all and then i posted here. Thanks for replay.