# pod install doesn't work when I try to get Realm 0.96.2

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, realm

I am try to follow some tutorial about Realm and iOS9 and I need to install Realm but after to create the pod init file and add this code:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'RealmTasks' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'RealmSwift'

end
```

I tried to do

```
pod install
```

but I am getting this error

```
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Realm (0.96.2)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
sh build.sh cocoapods-setup

core is not a symlink. Deleting...
Downloading dependency: core 0.94.0
Downloading core failed. Please try again once you have an Internet connection.
```

I read something about it on Github https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2446 and it mentioning about server problems and the last comment say about to download directly the last version. I try with that:

```
$ curl -f -L --verbose "https://static.realm.io/downloads/core/realm-core-0.94.0.tar.bz2" -o $TMPDIR/core_bin/core-0.94.0.tar.bz2
```

But, I get the same error...
Any ideas?? is there another way?? please. Thanks in advanced

Comment: What country are you in? Several countries are IP-blocked to comply with US export restrictions.

Comment: I am in Venezuela. I saw some countries have some problems with IP-blocked. But, Venezuela is not in the list.

Comment: Could you please send your public IP address to help@realm.io so we can see if Cloudflare is incorrectly labeling your IP to one of our blocked countries. This way we can scan our logs to get a better idea of why you're being blocked. Thanks!

Comment: I've just sent the email @jpsim. Thanks

Comment: @jpsim I think it was a internet issue because I try today and it work for me. However I tried to update cocoapods because I saw the suggestion in the console. I used 
**Updating spec repo master**
But that takes long time. I solved the problem with that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755974/cocoapods-pod-install-takes-forever

Answer (score 1):

Try one of two methods. 
1) Clean Xcode cache. Menu > Product > Clean 
2) Remove temporary download folder. In terminal run ( rm -rf /tmp/core_bin ) and reinstall pod by "pod install"

Answer (score 0):

You should download core via url first:

```
curl https://static.realm.io/downloads/core/realm-core-1.0.1.tar.bz2 -O
mkdir $TMPDIR/core_bin
mv realm-core-1.0.1.tar.bz2 $TMPDIR/core_bin
```