# iOS, GoogleMaps, Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key

Tags: ios, google-maps, xcode7

I am trying to upload archive for TestFlight testing in Xcode 7 and it gives me the error:

[image]

I tried to remove `CFBundleExecutable` key and set `CFBundlePackageType` to `BNDL`, the way it is recommended here:

[Unexpected CFBundleExecutable key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096130/unexpected-cfbundleexecutable-key)

and here:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8488

However, it starts giving me the following error:

[image]

My version of `google maps` is `1.11.0`

So, I am not sure what to try next. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to reinstall Google Maps from version `1.11.0` to `1.11.1`. No `info.plist` key changes/deletions were necessary. In the process I also faced the `pod install` command taking forever to run and used the appropriate solution:

[cocoapods - 'pod install' takes forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755974/cocoapods-pod-install-takes-forever)

Answer (score 0):

CFBundleSupportedPlatforms Replace with iPhoneSimulator to iPhoneOS in both 
GoogleMap.info -> info.plist and GSMCoreResources.bundle -> info.plist

Also remove Executable file property in GoogleMap.bundle -> info.plist  and GSMCoreResources.bundle -> info.plist