# CocoaPods not working

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I installed CocoaPods on a new machine.

My podfile file is just like this :

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'
```

But when I run **pod install**

```
Unable to find a specification for `MBProgressHUD (= 0.8)`.
```

I tried reinstalling CocoaPods, but didn't help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error on pod install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224627/error-on-pod-install)

Comment: Have you tried to remove the pod spec repo? `pod repo remove master`
and then do a `pod setup` again? I think the repo could be corrupted and reinstalling does not necessarily remove the repo.

Comment: @DanielBecker Yes, I did, no success.

Comment: Hi , Did you get this issue resolved? I am facing the same .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xcode-select --switch /applications/Xcode.app  
pod setup
pod install
```

[Cocoapods - Unable to find a Specification for [Github framework]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844013/cocoapods-unable-to-find-a-specification-for-github-framework)