# Unable to find a specification in CocoaPods xcode8.1

Tags: cocoapods, xcode8

I am getting error in both 'pod install' and 'pod update'

Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-pojectnam`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes

- MBProgressHUD

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
[!] Unable to find a specification for `MBProgressHUD (~> 0.9.2)`
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:442:in `handle_resolver_error'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:65:in`rescue in resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:57:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:723:in`block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:721:in`resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:76:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:236:in`analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:150:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in`section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:149:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:110:in`install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:37:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in`run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/bin/pod:55:in`'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in`'

This is error logs. I have tried installing cocoapods gem again , removing master repo but no luck.
Also i have tried manually **clone git specs** but its not woking its stopped after 90%

Comment: I think gems are not getting installed properly. I would recommend you to delete your podfile and reinstall gems and cocoapods again. For reference use this link https://cocoapods.org/. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Pointing directly to the git repo worked for me.  As an example replace the top line with the next one in your podfile:

```
replace this --> pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
    with this--> pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git'

replace this --> pod 'SwiftyJSON' , '~> 3.1'
    with this--> pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
```

For more on this see RaziPour1993's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844013/cocoapods-unable-to-find-a-specification-for-github-framework)