# Create a custom step indicator in iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer, progress-indicator

[image]

How do I create a progress indicator as shown in swift for iOS? Tried various libraries. But nothing fits exactly.The color should be in gradient and the current state must show the step number.

Comment: If you want to do this exactly how you want, you can create a subclass of `UIView` or `UIProgressView`, and make your own

Comment: Yes. I k now that. Just incase somebody has a solution to it (already done). Will save me a lot of time

Comment: Show your sample efforts so people would join in.

Comment: You could create this in just a few hours, there is nothing complicated about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create any custom control element You should inherits your class from UIControl. You can read about this here:
[custom knob](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5294-how-to-make-a-custom-control-tutorial-a-reusable-knob),
[custom slider](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2297-how-to-make-a-custom-control-tutorial-a-reusable-slider).

But You will have to write too many lines of code to create customize view.

However, You can use my turnkey solutions: https://github.com/vladislovshilov/StepView

Unfortunately this library does not support touch yet.

Comment: Hey Thanks @jMelvins. I don't need touch as if now. Guess this would work  Let me try it

Comment: is it possible to change the line color?

Comment: @AnupGPrasad yes, You should use lineBorderColor property for this.

Comment: If It helped you, can You please set my answer as correct. And star my lib on github. It is important for me, thank you!

Comment: It says [!] Unable to find a specification for `StepView`

Comment: Did you write "import StepView" in the head of your class?

Comment: Seems like the problem is on cocoapods.
Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844013/cocoapods-unable-to-find-a-specification-for-github-framework

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses a UIStackView, works nicely with auto layout, is animatable, and is configurable in Interface Builder.
https://gist.github.com/Dev1an/aa54ae331f4065569dc613d7f904bd54

Comment: How to add in project