# pod update - no such file

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

I get this error when doing a `pod update`.

```
pod update
[in /Users/snowcrash/myproject]
Update all pods
Analyzing dependencies
/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/pathname.rb:425:in `open': No such file or directory @ dir_initialize - /Users/snowcrash/.cocoapods/repos (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/pathname.rb:425:in `foreach'
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed as follows:

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods
pod setup
```

See also this:
[Error on pod install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224627/error-on-pod-install?rq=1)