# Xcode 8.0 swift 3.0 error Alamofire-swift.h not found and Could not build Objective-C module 'Alamofire'

Tags: ios, alamofire, swift3, ios10, xcode8

I converted my swift 2.2 project to swift 3.0. After updating my pod file, I get this error. Please see the attached image.

[image]

And here is the pod file content :

[image]

I do not know what part I am missing which has lead me to this error.

Can anyone help me out ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest first cleaning your project with `CMD+Shift+K` and then making sure your pods are correct with a `pod install`. If that doesn't work, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224627/error-on-pod-install) that involves clearing your pods. Whenever my pods get wonky I'll wipe them out and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

just open terminal and add you path for project and pod deintegrate after that just pod install