# Pod not compiling for simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Out of a sudden my project stopped compiling for `simulator` - everything works on real `device` but when I try to install to `simulator` it fails to compile two `pods` which were there a long time ago and used to work.

[image]

Another `pod` is `M13ProgressSuite` which also can't fine `NSNumberFormatter` though all the dependencies are there.

[image]

I suspect it started after I've removed `master repo` and inited pods over again as per other issue and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21468667/1713920) `SO` answer:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
```

I've never noticed any issues since I was working with `device` but now it appeared that I can't compile my project to test on `simulator`.

I've spent quite some hours trying to revert code in `git` to previous commit when it was working for `sure, reinint pods, remove/add the problematic pods, revert to previous versions of pods, clean/build project, restarting xcode, recreating simulator` - still the same error.

**Does anyone now why it may stuck with `simulator` though it used to work and keep working on real `device`? How can this issue be fixed?** I'm out of ideas but I need to be able to test in `simulator` since I'm developing for `watch`. Any clue is much appreciated.

> I'm using  Xcode 8.1,  iOS 10 target,  cocoapod version 1.1.1

Let me know if any additional information may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I'm able to keep working with simulator. **I've just redownloaded Xcode and reinstalled it** (moved to 8.2 actually) - as long as it solved the issue I'm fine with this solution but I'm still curious what went wrong and how should I've fixed it in a good way.

After spending more time I can add that copying the mentioned pods' sources into the project directly and removing them from pod file so they compile directly from sources in case there are any issues with the compiled frameworks still brought the same error - NSNumberFormatter.h was invisible though  import is there - this again work on device but fails to compile for simulator. This is where simulator became the main suspect but installing new one (by downloading a new simulator runtime) didn't solve the issue.