# Issue with installing Pods on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoapods, mbprogresshud

I am trying to install a pod, which I have done several 100 times before, never got this error before. Started getting this error, not sure what's wrong with it.

Here is my Podfile

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'MBProgressHUD'
```

Here is the error:

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
Setup completed (read-only access)
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing MBProgressHUD (0.8)
[!] Pod::Executable fetch origin tags/0.8 2>&1

fatal: Couldn't find remote ref tags/0.8

Unexpected end of command stream
```

I tried uninstalling cocoapods and reinstalled them, still the same

I tried removing the cache and tried to re install, still the same issue

i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970877/error-on-sudo-pod-install) as well, still same error.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your Podfile?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your remote repository does not have the tag `0.8`.

```
git push origin 0.8
```

Also, if you think the tag has already been pushed, make sure your podfile is looking at the correct remote. A fork may not have the correct tag.